# PHP - set a variable which does not neet to call using global

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a `variable` called

```
$variable
```

And when I call it inside a function then I need to use

```
some_function(){
global $variable;
echo $variable['array'];
}
```

But I dont want to use a `global` every time, Is there a way so by which I can call variable without setting a global everytime???

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

standard practice ...

```
some_function($variable){
echo $variable['array'];
}
```

called like any other function:

```
some_function($variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Pass` it as a parameter to your function

```
$variable=array(2,5,6,9,7);

some_function($param){
  print_r($param);  // this is your variable
}
```

call it like

```
some_function($variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use "global", you may use $GLOBALS superglobal variable:

```
function some_function() {
    echo $GLOBALS['variable']['array'];
}
```

$GLOBALS is an associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: I almost added this answer because it is different then the other options.  But users should really pass variables as parameters instead of accessing global variables.  Valid answer though.